# create LVM VG for /dev/sda2 root

Tags: centos, partition, virtual-machine, lvm, fdisk

How do I `pvcreate` and `vgcreate` the primary 480G SSD in CentOS 7 x64?

This is the command I would like to run in SSH: `vgcreate new_vol_group /dev/sda2`

But I get this error: `Can't open /dev/sda2 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?`

I'm trying to [add and create LVM based storage to Virtualizor](http://www.virtualizor.com/wiki/Add_New_Storage#LVM_Based_Storage) and am not having much luck. A moment ago, I successfully `vgcreate vg1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1` but now have problems trying to create vg for the primary SSD drive.

---

Virtualizor support said:

> Your /dev/sda2 partition is mounted on '/' so its not posssible to use it for panel as storage.
>
> To add a storage, please create a empty volume group and provide a name of volume group while adding a storage and enable primary storage option then it will be default storage for your panel
> *Note - please dont create lv just empty volume group.*

I thought these might be helpful:

```
[root@localhost ~]# lsblk
NAME                                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                                       8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk
├─sda1                                    8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                                    8:2    0   439G  0 part /
└─sda3                                    8:3    0   7.6G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb                                       8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sdb1                                    8:17   0 931.5G  0 part
  └─vg1-vsv1001--0pfq--bd2p7e5b9p0jendi 253:0    0     5G  0 lvm
sdc                                       8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sdc1                                    8:33   0 931.5G  0 part

[root@localhost ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       432G  6.1G  405G   2% /
devtmpfs         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            16G   25M   16G   1% /run
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       488M  167M  286M  37% /boot
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0
```

Comment: That pretty much sums it up; you can't reformat the volume you already installed to and are booted from for LVM... you need to set up LVM before or as part of the installation process so when you boot the installed system for the first time, it is already using LVM.

Answer (score 1):

You can't move `/dev/sda` directly to VG as it is already mounted and moreover there are files in the filesystem. The only procedure I know is next:

1. Make backup of your files to other disk. `/dev/sdc1` for example
2. Start installation, add `/dev/sda2` to VG
3. Allocate for `/` part of the VG. You do not need so much, 20GB will be fine as starting point.
4. You can create dedicated LVs for `/home`, `/var`, `/opt`,
   `/usr/local` depend of how you plan to use the system
5. Finish installation and restore your files from backup